# Indian e visa ETA date of expiry

Tags: india, visa-expiration, eta

I recently applied for Indian e-visa. Date of journey date I entered on the online application was Oct 3rd,2023. However Date of ETA expiry is Oct 5th. Could this be an error.
How to get this corrected.

Comment: Why do you think this is an error?

Comment: You have 3rd, 4th and 5th October as option to enter in India: they expect that there may be delay on your flight. The phrasing may not be optimal "ETA expiry", considering that the first is a generic *expected*.